# Getting this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage in Reactnative

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working in React native push notification using firebase , while i was trying to add logic to receive notification i got this error.

[image]

[Am following this link](https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591)